# Getting keys error while setup the Yocto environment in ubuntu

Tags: dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, yocto, gnupg, repo

I'm new to Yocto environment setup and using ubuntu 18.04 ,  while i am running the repo init -u https://link -b branch name -u .xml . Getting the error the below error

```
gpg: keybox '/root/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /root/.repoconfig/gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 16530D5E920F5C65: public key "Repo Maintainer <repo@android.kernel.org>" imported
gpg: key 67B7E448692B382C: public key "Conley Owens <cco3@android.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2

Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
object 8e91248655acf1c8044ed8c1b265b804a99eb07f
type commit
tag v2.21
tagger Mike Frysinger <vapier@google.com> 1643924845 -0500
repo v2.21

gpg: keyblock resource '/.repo/repo/root/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
gpg: Signature made Thu 03 Feb 2022 09:47:25 PM UTC
gpg:                using DSA key 8BB9AD793sahduidouqdhqod
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I'm not getting how to fix this . Please help on this

Comment: Do not build as root user. That is a terrible idea. What is the reason that you want to do it as root?

Comment: I'm using dockerfile for the installation , if i add new user getting the permission denied. How can i run instead of root user

Comment: just install sudo and yocto dependecies using apt, then use "useradd -G sudo -ms /bin/bash builduser" to add a new user, with this new user you can use sudo apt install <xy>. you should probably post your Dockerfile

Comment: root@dc0a23986:/# apt-get install -y  sudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sudo

Comment: did you try apt update before ?..

Comment: yes... i did update and ran the apt-get install -y sudo

Answer (score 0):

The file is being created here:

```
/root/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.kbx
```

That's why it cannot be found there:

```
/.repo/repo/root/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.kbx
```

Adding a sym-link might suffice to work around - or simply copy the file over.

Alternatively, see where the troublesome `/.repo/repo` prefix even comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I'm not getting.
Can you please explore or share any links or Doc's
How can I change because it's before /root I can not found the path or is there any alternate change the key locations